# Creating a custom Yasnippet with conditions

Tags: yasnippet

I have a yasnippet that is conflicting with `multiple-cursors` because it is not exiting immediately.  When `multiple-cursors` is not active, I would like the snippet to pause and permit me to enter the data.  Can I have an example, please, of a yasnippet that uses some `elisp` conditions:

For example,

```
(if mc-mode
  \hspace*{$0}
  \hspace*{$1})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yasnippet will accept `elisp` (including, but limited to conditions) provided that it is surrounded by *backticks*.  In the following example, `$0` will cause the snippet to automatically exit when `mc-mode` is `t`; whereas, `$1` will cause a pause at that location for user input when `mc-mode` is *nil*.

```
`(if mc-mode
    "\\\\hspace*{$0}"
    "\\\\hspace*{$1}")`
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`#condition` directive](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org185b594) to provide an `elisp` predicate. The snippet will only be expanded when the condition code you provide evaluates to non-nil. So, you could simply add this to your snippet:

```
# condition: (mc-mode)
```

Comment: I interpreted, perhaps incorrectly (?), the term `expand` to mean that yasnippet does what it is supposed to do.  And, that the `#condition` is designed to *prevent* yasnippet from functioning if the condition is satisfied.  Does the `#condition` affect the whole kitten-kaboodle (i.e., nothing at all should happen), or just whether to pause at position `$1` to wait for user input?

Comment: If the condition returns nil, the snippet will not be eligible for expansion. So, when `#condition` is `nil`, `yas-expand` behaves as if the snippet didn't exist. What it does instead of snippet expansion(assuming no other snippet is a match either) depends on the [fallback behaviour](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-reference.html#yas-fallback-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Another `condition` example that is simple enough but might be pretty handy in many projects with clear and stable structure.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: controller snippet foo
# condition: (cl-search "app/controllers/" buffer-file-name)
A snippet that activates only when:
(1) you're in corresponding major-mode
(2) your buffer file name is within "app/controllers/" path.
```

This should be pretty handy in case one has lots of snippets and want to exclude some of the based on the file directories they're called from.